# File creation time on GitHub actions

Tags: python, github-actions

I am running a GitHub action, and in GitHub action I need to get the time when the file was created. The file is from the respective repo on which I am running the action. I am using a python script to get the file creation time in GitHub action.

I don't know if it's actually possible, and just wanted to confirm if my reasoning of why it isn't is right. So the action runs the code in a docker container and files of the repository get copied to container, which essentially means they get created in docker container again. So the date of creation of file wouldn't be actual date but the date when they get copied into the container?

Comment: Why do you need to know when the files were created?

Comment: Can you simply not mount the volume instead of copying file to the container? What exactly is your use case?

Comment: I am trying to filter files based on when they were created and apply some function on filtered files. How do i mount in github action? I have created a github action and now I am using that github action in another repo, how do i mount there?